# Handling failed orders and upgrades via the WooCommerce Store API with subscription products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-subscriptions

Error “woocommerce_rest_product_not_purchasable” in Woocommerce store API.

Hello,

I used [WooCommerce Store API](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-blocks/tree/trunk/src/StoreApi),
I have subscription products for my customers, so when users don’t have any subscriptions or their subscription status is canceled then /wc/store/v1/cart/add-item it worked fine but if users attempt failed order then the subscription status is on-hold and their cart is empty,
How can set Pay last order using Store API,
I also try to use [/wc/store/v1/cart/add-item](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-blocks/blob/trunk/src/StoreApi/docs/cart.md#add-item) API for add to cart and re-payment for this subscription but getting a error response is,
error:

```
{
    "code": "woocommerce_rest_product_not_purchasable",
    "message": " ‘My_Subscription_Product’ is not available for purchase.",
    "data": {
        "status": 400
    }
}
```

And also when users want to upgrade the subscription product they also get the same as above response.